# Query to find if the list of columns that exists in the SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of columns. I want to build a query to find if the columns exists in the `ServicingDB` database.

We can also use the filter for the tables starting with abcd (example).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the table you can use `sp_columns TableName`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query  to find out the Specific column along with database name, table name etc.

```
select * from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'yourColumnName'
```